# Android SearchView not showing keyboard

Tags: android, searchview

```
<android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
        android:id="@+id/search_view"
        app:defaultQueryHint="Search By Company"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/greybg"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        app:searchHintIcon="@drawable/ic_search_black"
        app:closeIcon="@drawable/ic_search_close_black"
        app:iconifiedByDefault="false" />
```

`SearchView` not showing keyboard on single click inside `AutoCompleteTextView`, first it gains focus then on clicking again it opens keyboard. What I want is to show keyboard in single click by doing change only in XML code.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
searchView.setOnQueryTextFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasFocus) {
                        if (hasFocus) {
                             InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) 
                             getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                             if (imm != null) {
                             imm.showSoftInput(view, 0);
                             }
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
searchview.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if (hasFocus){
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED,0);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I know this way already, but here i wanted to ask it can I achieve it just by editing in XML.

Answer (score 0):

For that you can implement `setOnFocusChangeListener` on your `searchView` like shown below:

```
searchView.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasFocus) {
                if(hasFocus){
                    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    imm.showSoftInput(view, 0);
                }
            }
        });
```

Where context is your activity context.

Answer (score 0):

add attr clickable and focusable in EditText like below

```
<android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
        android:id="@+id/search_view"
        app:defaultQueryHint="Search By Company"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/greybg"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        app:searchHintIcon="@drawable/ic_search_black"
        app:closeIcon="@drawable/ic_search_close_black"
        app:iconifiedByDefault="false"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
        android:focusable="true" />
```